# How do i fix this program so it makes the input work if the password is in the dictionary and key value pair

Tags: python

```
userlist = {"MMonroe": "SomeLikeItHot1962",
            "NMandela": "Justice_27years",
            "ALincoln": "Number_16"}

username = input("What is you username? (FLastname)")
if username in userlist:
  passw = input("What is your password? :")
if passw   in username:
  passwnew = input("Enter password again:")
else:
    newac = input("password is invalid, try again or would you like to create a new account(y/n)?")

if input == "y":
  username = input("What is you username? (FLastname)")

  passw = input("What is your password? :")
  passwnew = input("Enter password again:")
else:
  print("Try again later or create new account")


if passw != passwnew:
     print("The password is invalid, try again")
else:
    print("Welcome to the website")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, please format your code properly as a code block.

Comment: If this code is for real-world use, please, please do not store your passwords like this. You should be using an existing library to store, updated, and authenicate passwords. Otherwise, for a project or demo, it's fine.

Comment: Also, you have lots of places where undeclared variables can be referenced. Look  at the first if: if `if username in userlist:` is evaluated and the condition is false -- then immediately afterwards you reference `passw` before it is declared.

Comment: when i executed the code the existing username works and when i put the password that is meant to go with the username it tells me to create a new password instead of giving me the password in the list

Comment: this is what i get:     What is you username? (FLastname) MMonroe
What is your password? : SomeLikeItHot1962
password is invalid, try again or would you like to create a new account(y/n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you meant to check if the password for that user was incorrect. Don't use `in` for that

```
if passw  != userlist[username]
```

Also, `if input == "y"` will never be true unless you overwrite the `input()` function with a string variable

Comment: theres still a problem with the (newac) variable, in the (if newac == "y":) the error says that newac is not defined even though it is before the if statement

Comment: That's a problem of variable scoping. The following if statement does not know the previous one happened or not. In other words, `else: newac = input` will not always run, and therefore, `newac` is never defined... You must set `newac = "n"` beforehand, outside of any conditions